# Call shell commands from Laravel controller?

Tags: php, shell, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to call Shell commands  (e.g for converting images ) from Laravel controller? If yes then how. I have searched on internet. Nothing seems relevant.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the Process component provided by Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

The component is used by Laravel itself, so your don't need to install it via composer separately. Just add `use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;` to your file.

If you use it(instead of php's `exec()` function), you'll be able to unit test the code that calls shell commands.

Comment: The Process component only seems to work with basic commands such as `ls`, `uname` and even `man`, but it doesn't seem to work with executables such as `ffmpeg`. There is no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @aalaap See if there is something in `$process->getErrorOutput()`

Comment: I found the solution on ffmpeg No output issue by removing empty characters in between the shell command. 

`` 'ffmpeg -i "concat:test1.mp3|test2.mp3|test3.mp3" -acodec copy' merged_file.mp3 ``

Remove the space characters in between the concat and the file.

Comment: Just to clarify, "The component is used by Laravel itself, so it can be loaded directly" means you don't need to install it separately. You can already do (e.g.) `use Symfony\Component\Process\Process; $process = new Process(['ls', '-lsa']); $process->run();`

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on what operating system you are using. php already has [a few functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to execute shell commands.

Laravel has a build in [task runner for ssh](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ssh) commands.

Comment: welcome to 2019! Are these functions deprecated for Laravel 5.8?

Answer (score -1):

```
$FilenamePending = "files".csv";
if (File::exists(public_path('downloads/files/wstock/'.$FilenamePending))){
$PathFilesWip=   public_path('downloads/files/wstock/'.$FilenamePending);
//$getCommand=   "aws s3 cp $PathFiles s3://bucket-name/share/in/test/Transaction/";
$getCommandPending=   "aws s3 cp $PathFilesWip s3://store_stocks/";
}else{
$getCommandPending=   "";
}
$schedule->exec($getCommandPending) ->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')->dailyAt('00:38')->appendOutputTo(storage_path().'/logs/laravel_output.log');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).