# Is it possible to execute command prompt from Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, command-prompt

Is it possible to execute command prompt from Laravel controller? If YES, then how can i execute a command and what is the best way to do this? If NO,is there any other way how i can do this?

Comment: yes you can use shell-commands

Comment: shell_exec('whoami')

Comment: How about PHP exec or shell-exec: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Also see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374495/run-sh-file-using-exec-laravel-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call shell commands from laravel controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527091/call-shell-commands-from-laravel-controller)

Answer (score 1):

I dont Know if I get it.
Cant you use 
PHP system()?
If I'm wrong please explain clearly

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: Actually, that was my bad, you did not really post a followup question, removed my comment (and will remove this tomorrow so it's clean here, hehe).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean with "command prompt" but you can execute commands directly from php with the `exec` function. This is often not a recommended approach though and I would suspect that it is possible that if you need to run `exec` there is a design issue in the application.

I would recommend that you consider other approaches to the problem and only use `exec` in **very** special conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to run artisan commands (e.g. migrating the database) you can easily do that from your controller:

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
        'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);

    //
});
```

Source: Laravel Docs

There are some packages available that give you a UI for calling Artisan commands, just search for "laravel artisan web".

---

If you need to execute other commands you should give us more information about what you're trying to do.