# How to execute external shell commands from laravel controller?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, shell, controller

I need to execute shell commands from controller , but not only for files inside the project , ex. system(**'rm /var/www/html/test.html'**) or system(**'sudo unzip /var/www/html/test.zip'**);

I call the function but nothing happen , any idea how to execute external shell commands from controller like removing one file in another directory?

```
system('rm /var/www/html/test.html');
//or
exec('rm /var/www/html/test.html')
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're wanting to run commands from your PHP application I would recommend using the [Symfony Process Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html):

1. Run `composer require symfony/process`
2. Import the class in to your file with `use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;`
3. Execute your command:

   ```
   $process = new Process(['rm', '/var/www/html/test.html']);

   $process->run();
   ```

If you're using Laravel, you should be able to skip Step 1.

---

Alternatively, (if the process running php has the correct permissions) you could simply use PHP's [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function to delete the file:

```
unlink('/var/www/html/test.html');
```

Comment: i tried this but Symfony Process executes commands only inside project directory , when I do $process = new Process(['rm', '/var/www/another_directory/test.html']) , it doesnt execute

Comment: @AnonS In that case I would imagine you have a permissions issue. What operating system are you using?

Comment: i am using linux

Comment: you were right , it was permission issue ,i gave it 755 and www-data and it works like charm , thanks

Comment: You don't need to install it, it's already included with Laravel. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27857423/135101.

Comment: @TylerCollier You are absolutely right. That being said, someone could come looking for the answer to something like this who isn't using Laravel. I was trying to write this answer to apply to PHP in general (not just Laravel).

Comment: @Rwd you could mention that, as in the link I provided. Otherwise someone using Laravel, might install it unnecessarily, like I did.

Comment: @TylerCollier Yeah, I can do. Do you run into any issues (excluding a possible conflict message during `composer update`)?

Comment: @Rwd No, there was no issue when I installed it separately, but I think as you are alluding, makes it more likely to run into conflicts later.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this with what the framework already provide:

1) First generate a command class:

```
php artisan make:command TestClean
```

This will generate a command class in App\Console\Commands

Then inside the handle method of that command class write:

```
@unlink('/var/www/html/test.html');
```

Give your command a name and description and run:

```
php artisan list
```

Just to confirm your command is listed.

2) In your controller import Artisan facade.

```
use Artisan;
```

3) In your controller then write the following:

```
Artisan::call('test:clean');
```

Please refer to the docs for further uses:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#generating-commands

Comment: this will not work for my situation ,anyway thanks, good solution

Comment: @AnonS I think like Ross mentioned its a permission issue, maybe you should simply check what output you get from `exec('rm /var/www/html/test.html', $output); var_dump($output);` and share it with us

Comment: the output is empty

Comment: my bad that should of be `exec('rm /var/www/html/test.html 2>&1', $output); var_dump($output);`

Answer (score 3):

Use fromShellCommandline to use direct shell command:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('rm /var/www/html/test.html');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: i have forgot $process=
Process::fromShellCommandline('.....