# Deploy Laravel app programatically on Heroku and connect to existing git repository

Tags: laravel, heroku, cloudflare

I have a laravel app, that seeks to use the same codebase, how can I programatically create an app on heroku via Laravel whenever I create a new user on the app. And also generate a DNS nameserver to use for custom domain which I do on cloudflare

Comment: you would most likely have to use the heroku cli and laravel and run "process" shell commands from laravel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266041/how-to-execute-external-shell-commands-from-laravel-controller.  Otherwise, look to the API https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.