# Laravel error : Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PageController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm learning Laravel, I just uploaded my project to web hosting. But when I run the website, I get the error message

> file_put_contents() failed to open stream no such file or directory hosting

Then I tried to reset-cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan event:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan view:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan event:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

After I ran the command, another error message appeared:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PageController] does not exist.

I've made sure that the `PageController` is in the `App\Http\Controllers` directory.

What happened?  How do I fix it?

I've tried clearing cache, changing routes, but nothing works.

Comment: How did you deploy your app? git? copy paste via ftp? if all files were properly added in the right places, try to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I just copy paste the project via FTP. The web hosting I have does not have a CLI/terminal feature, so I run a cache reset using `Artisan::call`, unfortunately, I have tried calling dump-autoload via `Artisan::call('sump-autoload')` but it doesn't work, I get the error message "The command "dump -autoload"does not exist.". Are there any steps I missed before uploading the project?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is the filename for this Controller `PageController.php` and the class defined in it is `PageController`? trying to rule out case sensitivity issues with the filesystem

Comment: Make sure the namespace is correct

Comment: @lagbox  Hi, yes that's right, I'm sure that the filename and class defined was correct, I even copied and pasted the file name into the defined section.

Comment: @Mihai I'm sorry, what is a namespace?

Comment: dump-autoload is not an artisan command.

Comment: Did you run the `php artisan` commands via `Artisan` Facade? If so, you will need to run `composer` commands via a different Facade: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54266370

Comment: In the place where you added the `Artisan::call`, change to `$process = new Process(['composer', 'dump-autoload']); $process->run();`

Comment: add your controller and ``routes/web.php`` complete code.

Answer (score 1):

if your page is 404, that mean error on route, you can check your route:list and make sure the route has been detected, and do `php artisan optimize`

if your controller does not exist, maybe you forgot to write use or maybe typo, it happen a lot at me too

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
// ADD THIS ! dont forget use
use App\Http\Controllers\SomeController;

Route::get('something', [SomeController::class, 'index']);
```

or use this old format so you dont need use

```
Route::get('/something','App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@index');
```

Comment: Of course I have done it, there is no problem when I run it locally, but the problem occurs after I deploy my project to hosting.

Comment: If it runs locally and not on your server, doublecheck the filename. Pagecontroller.php will work locally, but on most servers only PageController.php will work (case sensitivity)