# puppeteer working properly on localhost but not on my ubuntu server

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, ubuntu, puppeteer

I have a simple laravel project that you can add a website, take a screenshot of that website, and display all the website to the homepage.

My script works great on localhost

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function takeScreenshot(url, path) {
    try {
        console.log("Launching browser...");
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ["--no-sandbox"],
        });
        console.log("Browser launched successfully");

        console.log("Opening new page...");
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log("New page opened successfully");

        console.log("Setting viewport...");
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
        console.log("Viewport set successfully");

        console.log("Navigating to URL:", url);
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
        console.log("Navigation to URL completed successfully");

        console.log("Taking screenshot...");
        await page.screenshot({ path: path });
        console.log("Screenshot taken successfully");

        console.log("Closing browser...");
        await browser.close();
        console.log("Browser closed successfully");

        console.log("Screenshot saved to:", path);

        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while taking screenshot:", error);
        return false;
    }
}

const url = process.argv[2];
const path = process.argv[3];

takeScreenshot(url, path)
    .then((success) => {
        if (success) {
            console.log("Screenshot taken for", url);
        } else {
            console.error("Failed to take screenshot for", url);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
    });
```

and on my laravel controller i have this

```php
$command = "node $scriptPath $escapedUrl $storagePath";
Log::info("Executing command: $command");

exec($command, $output, $returnvar);
Log::info("Return Value: $returnvar");
Log::info($output);
```

this is the result of the log files on my localhost

```
[2024-02-28 08:10:49] local.INFO: Executing command: node pathtomyproject\node_scripts/screenshot.js "https://github.com/" pathtomyproject\storage\app/public/screenshots/008ec4453ff31513f43893cba7aa31c8_20240228081049.png  
[2024-02-28 08:10:52] local.INFO: Return Value: 0  
[2024-02-28 08:10:52] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 'Launching browser...',
  1 => 'Browser launched successfully',
  2 => 'Opening new page...',
  3 => 'New page opened successfully',
  4 => 'Setting viewport...',
  5 => 'Viewport set successfully',
  6 => 'Navigating to URL: https://github.com/',
  7 => 'Navigation to URL completed successfully',
  8 => 'Taking screenshot...',
  9 => 'Screenshot taken successfully',
  10 => 'Closing browser...',
  11 => 'Browser closed successfully',
  12 => 'Screenshot saved to: pathtomyproject\\storage\\app/public/screenshots/008ec4453ff31513f43893cba7aa31c8_20240228081049.png',
  13 => 'Screenshot taken for https://github.com/',
)
```

but on my server where i deploy my this project i have this log instead

```
[2024-02-28 08:14:47] local.INFO: Executing command: node /var/www/sitechecker/node_scripts/screenshot.js 'https://github.com/' /var/www/sitechecker/storage/app/public/screenshots/1bab3f16e219f6242b86db0c18e33cfd_20240228081447.png  
[2024-02-28 08:14:47] local.INFO: Return Value: 0  
[2024-02-28 08:14:47] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 'Launching browser...',
)
```

this is my first time using node on my ubuntu server, so i am having a hard time trying to locate the issue, is it the js file or or my laravel project, or maybe my server

i tried reloading the server, changing the node version to v18.17.1 (since that is my node version on my localhost) and return it back to 20.11.1, but still the same result.

basically i want the result of my server log to be the same on my localhost

Comment: Looks like browser isn't being launched. Check if you have chromium installed on your server. You can specify the executable path for chromium in puppeteer launch options, e.g.: ```puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
})```

Comment: Are you sure this problem is relatd to PHP or Laravel after all?

Comment: @OrionCygnus i tried running the command via terminal, it works great, but i still try to check if chromium is installed and apparently it is not, so i've installed it but still having the same result on the log file

@NicoHaase to be honest, i dont know, but past errors that i already been fix is `exec()` function not running, so i am just thinking if doing that affects the output, but i guess the main issue is on the server side

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. Just to understand: running the exact same node command works on the terminal, but not when launched using PHP?

Comment: Would it work better if you checked for problems with the execution, like recommended at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266041/how-to-execute-external-shell-commands-from-laravel-controller?